# How to prevent the player from clicking too fast

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, input

I'm having trouble with some bullets in my game, the M1911, which is supposed to be semi-auto is only capable of shooting one projectile per mouse click (trying to learn how to do multiple ones at once). The problem is, if the player clicks the mouse ridiculously fast it causes the bullet to reset its position back to the player (not intended).

Basically I want to limit the clicks, or implement a cooldown after the left mouse buttons pressed which prevents the player from clicking at all during a certain timeframe (or until the bullet hits something).

I want it so that when LMB is pressed it starts a timer.

Comment: If everything runs on one thread keep in mind that your "while" is preventing  your program to continue while that statement is true.

Comment: Do you really only have one bullet that is teleported back when pressing LMB? This will cause issues when you start guns with a higher fire-rate. You need to have a pool of bullets and some max lifetime per bullet :).

Comment: well its just for the M1911 which is semi auto, I'm still learning on how to do that lol :3 If you know a good tutorial somewhere can you link me plz? thx

Answer (score 7):

The usual way to handle this is that every time a bullet is fired you set some variable to your cooldown time.  Every frame you decrement that variable by the frame time.  If you try to fire and that value is greater than 0, you just ignore the fire input event.

If that feels bad, a next step is to queue up a "they want to fire" action if they try to click when the cooldown is happening and execute on it when the timer passes zero.

Comment: so what I do is I make it so that when they click the variable is set to 1 (for example) and if the variable equals 1 then the left mouse button is disabled, then after the time I want it to cooldown passes, set it back to 0?

Comment: OH no wait, Its like a countdown timer huh? the bullet is fired and the variable (lets say 50 or something) is subtracted by the frames being generated, and if the value isn't 0 then the bullet can't be fired?

Comment: Generally you don't want to use frames unless you're frame locked at 60hz and know you're not going to drop below that.  It's better to use actual seconds (stored as a float or whatever).  But more or less that's accurate.

Comment: Take a look at GameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds :)